# How to update a database using LINQ to SQL?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm new to using LINQ. I know there are many different posts on this subject but most of them are older and don't work for my situation (or I'm doing something else wrong).

I have a form that when it loads it creates the data context. I have a secondary form where a user can select a path and that path is updated in a configuration table that has one row.

This is the definition of the Configuration class...

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.Configuration")]
public partial class Configuration : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);

    private int _Id;

    private string _LegalRepository;

    private string _TitleRepository;

    private bool _AlwaysOpenOnDesktop;

#region Extensibility Method Definitions
partial void OnLoaded();
partial void OnValidate(System.Data.Linq.ChangeAction action);
partial void OnCreated();
partial void OnIdChanging(int value);
partial void OnIdChanged();
partial void OnLegalRepositoryChanging(string value);
partial void OnLegalRepositoryChanged();
partial void OnTitleRepositoryChanging(string value);
partial void OnTitleRepositoryChanged();
partial void OnAlwaysOpenOnDesktopChanging(bool value);
partial void OnAlwaysOpenOnDesktopChanged();
#endregion

    public Configuration()
    {
        OnCreated();
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_Id", AutoSync=AutoSync.OnInsert, DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY", IsPrimaryKey=true, IsDbGenerated=true)]
    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return this._Id;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._Id != value))
            {
                this.OnIdChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._Id = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("Id");
                this.OnIdChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_LegalRepository", DbType="NVarChar(100) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string LegalRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return this._LegalRepository;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._LegalRepository != value))
            {
                this.OnLegalRepositoryChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._LegalRepository = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("LegalRepository");
                this.OnLegalRepositoryChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_TitleRepository", DbType="NVarChar(100) NOT NULL", CanBeNull=false)]
    public string TitleRepository
    {
        get
        {
            return this._TitleRepository;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._TitleRepository != value))
            {
                this.OnTitleRepositoryChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._TitleRepository = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("TitleRepository");
                this.OnTitleRepositoryChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    [global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_AlwaysOpenOnDesktop", DbType="Bit NOT NULL")]
    public bool AlwaysOpenOnDesktop
    {
        get
        {
            return this._AlwaysOpenOnDesktop;
        }
        set
        {
            if ((this._AlwaysOpenOnDesktop != value))
            {
                this.OnAlwaysOpenOnDesktopChanging(value);
                this.SendPropertyChanging();
                this._AlwaysOpenOnDesktop = value;
                this.SendPropertyChanged("AlwaysOpenOnDesktop");
                this.OnAlwaysOpenOnDesktopChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

The creation of the database context...

```
public partial class fmFileSearch : Form
{
    public Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

    public FileSearchDataContext fileSearchDB = new FileSearchDataContext();

    public fmFileSearch()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        ReadConfiguration();
    }
```

I can read the row...

```
configuration = (from c in fileSearchDB.Configurations where c.Id == 1 select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

But when I try to update the row it doesn't update...

```
configuration.TitleRepository = locateRepository.SelectedPath;

fileSearchDB.SubmitChanges();
```

The table has a primary key and when I look at the configuration object in storage it has the new value.

Why won't the database update?

UPDATED: I added the code to show how the database context is created along the constructor for the class where I call the routine to read the row.

UPDATE 2: If I read the row this way it works...

```
var query =
    from c in fileSearchDB.Configurations
        where c.Id == 1
        select c;

    foreach (Configuration c in query)
    {
        configuration = c;
    }
```

Why??

Comment: what is locateRepository?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: locateRepository is a form where the user can select a folder to add files to.

Comment: Gary.. not an answer to your question... but I suggest you read my blog www.samwheat.com for some ideas on how to design your app as n-tier and how to design repositiry and service layers.  This will save you from running into problems such as this one.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `fileSearchDB` on this line

```
configuration = (from c in fileSearchDB.Configurations where c.Id == 1 select c).SingleOrDefault();
```

is actually the same db context in this

```
fileSearchDB.SubmitChanges();
```

because it could be that in first line is one db context and the in the second line is another db context.

make sure they share the same db context, try to make the following:

```
using(var fileSearchDb = new MyFileSearchDbContext())
{
    var configuration = (from c in fileSearchDB.Configurations where c.Id == 1 select c).SingleOrDefault();
    configuration.TitleRepository = locateRepository.SelectedPath;
    fileSearchDB.SubmitChanges();

}
```

Comment: The routine where I read the configuration is different than the one where I update it. Do I have to read it and update it in the same routine?

Comment: I only have one fileSearchDB that is defined as a global variable.

Comment: Can u please update ur question to show us how u initialize ur fileSearchDb?

Comment: Can anyone see where I am going wrong? If I'm using the same context the database should update.